# Arduino serial communication with serial encoder

Tags: arduino, serial-port, atmega

I am currently trying to communicate with an absolute encoder over serial, and as you can see from the picture below, it is responding fine to my requests, but the problem I am having is arduino is not reading the response bytes correctly all the time. The request from the encoder for position is the command 0x64 which responds with 4 bytes which consist of an echo byte (0x64 in picture), two bytes of data (0xAD and 0x53 in picture), and a error byte (0x00 in picture). What I am currently doing is sending the command, reading 4 bytes and as a way of debugging I am writing the response of the echo byte back to the serial port (0x18 in picture). As you can see 0x18 != 0x64 so I'm wondering where I am going wrong. I have double checked the baudrate and I'm talking at the correct speed, I just cannot seem to get a consistent read on the response. Below is a simplified version of the code that I have been running to try and fix this issue. The `delayMicroseconds()` is just there to separate the bytes on the oscilloscope.

[image: Oscilloscope image of communication]

```
  Serial.write(0x64);
  byte echo_byte = 0;
  byte pos_1 = 0;
  byte pos_2 = 0;
  byte status_byte = 0;
  echo_byte = Serial.read();
  pos_1 = Serial.read();
  pos_2 = Serial.read();
  status_byte = Serial.read();
  delayMicroseconds(1000);
  Serial.write(echo_byte)
```

Comment: Use `Serial.write(0x18)` instead of `Serial.write(echo_byte)` on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You must check and wait until there is a byte available to read on the port before calling Serial.read().  If there are no bytes available for reading, Serial.read() returns -1.

as in:

```
byte echo_byte = 0;
byte pos_1 = 0;
byte pos_2 = 0;
byte status_byte = 0;

Serial.write(0x64);

while (Serial.available() < 4)  // wait for the 4 byte message.
    ; 

Serial.read(echo_byte);
Serial.read(pos_1);
Serial.read(pos_2);
Serial.read(status_byte);
```

This is a bit cumbersome, and prone to errors, so Serial.readBytes is usually used for mylti-byte transfers, as in:

```
// Reads position from encoder, returns true if pos is valid.
bool read_pos(unsigned short& pos)
{
    struct pos_msg 
    {
        byte echo_byte;
        unsigned short pos;
        byte status;
    };

    Serial.write(0x64);

    pos_msg msg;
    Serial.readBytes((char*)&msg, sizeof(msg));

    if (msg.echo_byte != 0x64 || msg.status != 0)
        return false;

    pos = msg.pos;
    return true;
}
```